# 'COPY INTO' - problem with arrays with None in S3 files

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We're importing zipped csv files from an S3 stage to Snowflake with a simple COPY INTO command. One of the columns can have values like:

```
[None, None, 'some-string-here']
[None]
[]
```

etc.
That's how they look in the file.
In Snowflake they should translate to: `[null, null, "some-string-here"], [null], []`.
The column in Snowflake is of type ARRAY.

I played around with changing the file format to handle this, but no luck. It works perfectly with columns other than arrays, but items in an array don't get translated with NULL_IF declared values.

The below is an exemplary error:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 100069 (22P02): None: Error parsing JSON: [None]
```

Could you please advise on:
-> if it's possible to tweak the import without changing the input file
-> if the file change is absolutely necessary, what would be the best structure of data in the input file?

Comment: Need more detail please. Save it to a file if snowflake can't understand that `None` is the equivalent of null

Comment: @Yiannis it is coming from a file, in the csv those are the values:
...,[None,None,'some-string-here'],...
...,[None],...
...,[],...

Comment: Right, ok. So pandas translates `None` to null with the df.to_csv method, have you tried that?

Comment: Okay if the file has `None` instead of `null`, that's what's wrong

Comment: Are you generating that file? Whoever is responsible for that file, is doing it wrongly

Comment: The file is saved using df.to_csv. Is there any way to handle this without changes to the file?